# Conditionally inserting MySQL entries in a Flask app

Tags: python, sql, flask

I am a newbie in back-end developing. I know that the biggest part of back-end development is interaction with database.

I established a connection and the code is 100% working, but I am wondering if it is well optimized. There is one function where I make double insertion into the database but before I commit this insertion I make two requests to the database to determine whether I should insert or not.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, url_for
import MySQLdb

def connection():
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='somehost',
                           user='root',
                           passwd='some password',
                           db='users_addresses',
                           port=3306
                           )
    c = conn.cursor()
    return c, conn

def processing():
    # some actions
    try:
        c, conn = connection()
        c = conn.cursor()
        mc_address_existence, id = mc_address_exist(c, conn, mc_address=box_id)
        if mc_address_existence and not login_exist(c, conn, login):

            c.execute("INSERT INTO accounts_info (uid, first_name, second_name, email, phone_number) "
                      "VALUES ({},"
                            " '{}',"
                            " '{}', "
                            "'{}',"
                            " {} ) ".format(id, first_name, second_name, email, phone_number)
                      )

            c.execute("INSERT INTO logins_passwords (uid, login, password) "
                      "VALUES ({},"
                      "'{}',"
                      " '{}' ) ".format(id, login, password)
                      )
            conn.commit()
            c.close()
            conn.close()
            return jsonify({'result': True})
        return jsonify({'result': False})
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)
```

And here are two functions for determining whether to make the insertion or not:

```
def mc_address_exist(c, conn, mc_address):
    # Should I wrap it for try/except?
    # c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT uid, mc_address "
              "FROM boxes_id "
              "WHERE mc_address='{}' ".format(mc_address))
    res = c.fetchall()
    # c.close() Should I close?
    # conn.close()
    if res:
        return True, res[0][0]
    return False, 0


def login_exist(c, conn, login):
    # should I wrap it for try/except?
    c.execute("SELECT * "
              "FROM logins_passwords "
              "WHERE login='{}' ".format(login))
    res = c.fetchall()
    # c.close() should I close it or not?
    # conn.close()
    if res:
        return True
    return False
```

It is working code, but maybe not optimized. Here are three questions:

- Should I close the cursor `(conn, c)` in the checking functions?
- Should I wrap the database's selection checking functions into try/except?
- Maybe I should use `with as` instead?

Comment: You might also find this discussion interesting https://stackoverflow.com/q/9845102/1190388

Comment: Please see *[What to do when someone answers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*. I have rolled back Rev 5 → 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def connection():
```

This is misnamed. Please call it `cursor_connection()`, as that is the tuple it returns. Some folks would prefer the identifier `curs` over the rather ambiguous `c`, as "cursor" and "connection" both start with that letter.

```
    c, conn = connection()
    c = conn.cursor()
```

Ok, that 2nd line is just bizarre. Please delete it, as the function already accomplished that task.

Nice little INSERT you have there. Be a shame if some punctuation crept into it:  https://www.xkcd.com/327/

```
except Exception as e:
```

What is your concern, here? Might be better to elide the try / catch altogether, since there isn't really any "error recovery code" here.

Rather than having mc_address_exist() return a tuple, it would be more natural to return a (potentially empty) list, or return a scalar that potentially is None (assuming the uid column is declared NOT NULL). It's not clear why you asked the DB to retrieve mc_address, since you just discard it.

In login_exist(), rather than asking for `*`, it would be a cheaper query to just `select count(*)`.

You're not leaking anything with that cursor, so don't worry about closing it. You are correctly closing the underlying TCP connection. Your try/catch handling appears to be adequate for your needs at present, so no change needed.

Answer (score 1):

J_H provides some good feedback. In addition, I would suggest that you combine your SQL statements into a single statement, to reduce traffic back-and-forth to the database.

Your code is really asking "do these entries exist in the tables?" So ask that! Use a nested select to ask your two different questions, and just do a `COUNT()` on them. If they're 1 and 1-or-more, you're good to proceed:

```
SELECT COUNT(logins) == 1 AND COUNT(addresses) >= 1
  FROM 
    (SELECT uid FROM boxes_id WHERE mc_address='{}') AS addresses,
    (SELECT login FROM logins_passwords WHERE login='{}') AS logins
```